# 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp' in ShapeFile

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, gis

I have prediction map that most use Timestamp data, I plot the result and I want to save it as ESRI shapefile but I couldn't because of the error of pandas, you may wanna look to the [notebook](https://www.mediafire.com/file/be9d2lyiy2qgijl/5_ploting_Resoult.ipynb/file) file the code at the last cell..

here is sample of the code

```
#test_df['probability'] = np.minimum(pred,0.300)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

fig.set_size_inches((15,15))

test_df.plot(ax=ax,column='probability',cmap=cmap)

plt.gca().set_facecolor('k')

plt.imshow(np.array([[test_df.probability.min(),test_df.probability.max()]]),origin='lower',cmap=cmap)

test_collisions.plot.scatter(x='Longitude',y='Latitude',

                         ax=ax,
                         s=500,
                         color='w',
                         zorder=9e99,
                         marker='*',
                         edgecolors='r')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

ax.set_xbound(lower=x0,upper=x1)

ax.set_ybound(lower=y0,upper=y1)
plt.colorbar(cax=cax)

test_df.to_file('MyGeometriesSRSH-sout.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

and i got this back

```
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Any suggestions